# Importing web project to Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, web

i have a web project, how can i open this in Eclipse. I just have src folder and WebContent folder.
Shall i need to create a web project and then add these two folders or copy them to existing project?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new project, navigate to the project directory and replace files with the code. Don't forget to press F5 to refresh eclipse after it.

Comment: please don`t forget to choose the best solution for you as accepted solution here, so other users will find out that it is workable easier.

Answer (score 0):

If they are part of another project then I would import them otherwise I would just create a new project for them.  Either way you'll need to create the project and import the folders into it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply open your project folder as new project in the Eclipse IDE.

> File > New > New Project > Create Project at existing location (from
>   existing source) > (select your project folder)